# Evaluate $\int{\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+8}}{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

So I've tried solving the equation below by using $u=x+8$, and I get $\int{\frac{\sqrt[3]{u}}{u-8}}du$ which doesn't seem to lead anywhere, I've also tried taking the $ln$ top and bottom, but I don't know how to proceed. Any hints?

$$\int{\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+8}}{x}}dx$$ 
Update: Using partial fraction decomposition, $A=2, B=-2, C= -8$ (thank you to all the helpful posts) and after some tedious calculations, the answer I obtained was: $3{\sqrt[3]{x+8}}+24(2ln|\sqrt[3]{x+8}-2|-2ln|\sqrt[3]{x+8}+2|+{\frac{4}{\sqrt[3]{x+8}+2}})+C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=u^3-8$, then $\mathrm dx =3u^2\mathrm du$ and we get the integral
$$\int\frac{u}{u^3-8}3u^2\mathrm du$$
Last integral can be solved by partial fractions since

\begin{align*}
\frac{3u^3}{u^3-8}&=3+\frac{24}{u^3-8}\\
&=3+\frac{A}{u-2}+\frac{Bu+C}{u^2+2u+4}
\end{align*}

where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are constants we must find.

Answer (score 1):

you can start with
$$\begin{align}
u^3=x+8&\Rightarrow 3u^2du=dx\\
x=u^3-8\\
\int\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+8}}{x}dx&=\int\frac{\sqrt[3]{u^3}}{u^3-8}(3u^2du)\\
&=\int\frac{3u^3}{u^3-8}\\
&=\int\frac{3(u^3-8)+24}{u^3-8}du\\
&=\int3+\frac{24}{u^3-8}du
\end{align}$$